# Derivative has Linear Growth Implies Lipshitz

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$. If $f$ has linear growth i.e

$$|\nabla f(x)|\leq C(|x|+1)$$

then is $f$ Lipshitz?

attempt at proof :

by Mean Value Theorem there exists $c\in (0,1)$ such that 
\begin{align*}
|f(x)- f(y)| \leq |\nabla f((1-c)x+cy)||x-y|\leq & C(|x-y|+1)|x-y|
\\
\leq& C(|x-y|^2+|x-y|)
\\
\leq& C(2|x-y|^2+1).
\end{align*}

Comment: It's a funny usage of *linear growth*. Usually, I would understand "linear growth" as "the function grows linearly", rather than "the derivative is linear". A function with linear growth in your sense is not Lipschitz in general, whereas in my sense it's always Lipschitz.

Comment: Sure, I changed the growth condition to derivative has linear growth. What kind of growth would you normally call this ?

Comment: Cuadractic growth. Then again this may be field-dependent, maybe the literature you are working with agrees with your usage of linear growth!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbf R^1$. Then $|\nabla f(x)| = |f'(x)| = 2|x| \le 2(|x|  +  1)$ for all $x$, yet $f$ is not Lipschitz.